# CodeIgniter Search Database based on an undefined number of fields?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, search

long time searcher here first time asker.

I am using codeigniter to create a system where a user can use a series of fields in a form to search for a result. None of the fields are required but instead can be used to condense the results. I have it working in straight php which is below but after some serious searching i cannot wrap my head around how to get the functionality working in CodeIgniter. I am new to the software too. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Index.php

```
<form action="site/searchcharacter.php" method="post" class="form" id="searchForm">
        <legend>Search AnimeDB</legend>
        <select name="gender"><option>None</option><option>Male</option><option>Female</option></select>
        <select name="approx_age"><option>None</option><option>Baby</option><option>Todler</option><option>Child</option><option>Teen</option><option>Adult</option><option>Senior</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="hair_colour" class="input-small" placeholder="Hair Colour">
        <select name="hair_length"><option>None</option><option>Hair Above Ears</option><option>Hair Below Ears</option><option>Hair Below Shoulders</option><option>Hair Below Waist</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="eye_colour" class="ut-small" placeholder="Eye Colour">
        <select name="ear_type"><option>None</option><option>Human Ears</option><option>Cat Ears</option><option>Dog Ears</option><option>Horns</option><option>Other</option></select>
        <input type="text" name="weapons" class="input-small" placeholder="Weapons">
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_button" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

searchcharacter.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE 1=1";

    if ($gender != "None") {
        if (!empty($gender)) {
            $query = $query . " AND gender='$gender'";
        }
    }

    if ($age != "None") {
        if(!empty($age)) {
            $query = $query . " AND approx_age='$age'";
        }
    }


    if(!empty($hairColour)) {
        $query = $query . " AND hair_colour='$hairColour'";
    }

    if ($hairLength != "None") {
        if(!empty($hairLength)) {
            $query = $query . " AND hair_length='$hairLength'";
        }
    }

    if(!empty($eyeColour)) {
        $query = $query . " AND eye_colour='$eyeColour'";
    }

    if ($earType != "None") {
        if(!empty($earType)) {
            $query = $query . " AND ear_type='$earType'";
        }
    }

    if(!empty($weapons)) {
        $query = $query . " AND weapons='$weapons'";
    }

    //Prepare and Exec
    $STH = $DBH->query($query);
```

Comment: dont you need to Concatenate those queries?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is. $query = $query . "Added bit";

Comment: Have you checked out the CodeIgniter's documentation on Active Records (for database queries)? It's very handy and should help you out a lot. Extremely handy, I use them all the time. And they also auto-escape data thrown at them.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Yeah i have had a solid look through there but haven't found a function which could handle what i need. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Just posted an answer using ARs, does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start you off with Active Records -

```
if ($gender != "None" && !empty($gender))
{
  $this->db->where('gender', $gender);
}
```

You can then repeat this for your other checks since multiple wheres are added as chained ANDs.

Then you call `$query_result = $this->db->get('characters');`

Comment: No problem. Take a look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html if you need help converting CodeIgniter's result object into a usable array.